# issues with IE and jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I have the following function which works fine in every browser but IE.  When loading one image and then going back and clicking on the same `<a>` tag the image fades out but does not load back in.  I am puzzled to why this works in other browsers but not in IE.  Any and all insight greatly appreciated.

```
$('a').click(function({
  $("#el").animate({
       opacity: 0
     }, 800,
     function(){
       $("<img/>").attr('src', 'http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png').load(function(){
           $("#el img").attr('src', "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png")
           $("#el").animate({
             opacity: 1
           }, 
           800)
       });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the load-function **before** setting the src.

The image is in the cache after the first click, so it will be loaded immediately, the `.load()` comes to late.

Comment: I am using this for a slideshow and need to make sure that the href of the link that is clicked is loaded before fading the element back in.  Is this not the correct way to go about this?  I generally use this code or very similar for slideshows.

Comment: load() will fire when an image has been loaded, so you can be sure that the image has been loaded yet. The problem you have with your current code is that the image has been loaded before you assign the load-function, that's all.

Comment: See the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/F6ECx/ . It doesn't change the logic of your approach, the only significant change is that it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with how IE handles opacity. [Quirksmode on opacity](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)